# Custom Sound For UILocal NOtificaton

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

i want custom sound like runtime recorded message should be played for Alaram alert
but how we can it be possible ?

Comment: Look to a column at right of your question. It called **Related**, now I see there a plenty of the same questions.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
UILocalNotification *ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 ln.soundName = [NSString @"mysound.wav"]; 
 ...
```

Comment: but i want recorded file at runtime